# SqlException was unhandled by user code (parameterized query)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

public Account getAccount(string userID)
        {
            Account accountFound = null;

```
        string Name, Password, Email, PhoneNum, Address;

        string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM Account WHERE userID = @userID ";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", userID);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            userID = dr["UserID"].ToString();
            Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            Password = dr["Password"].ToString();
            Email = dr["Email"].ToString();
            PhoneNum = dr["PhoneNum"].ToString();
            Address = dr["Address"].ToString();


            accountFound = new Account(userID, Name, Password, Email, PhoneNum, Address);
        }

        conn.Close();
        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();

        return accountFound;
    }
```

Hi guys! I have an error with my program. Above are my codes! 
Error message : 
SqlException was unhandled by user code
The parameterized query '(@userID nvarchar(4000))SELECT*FROM Account WHERE userID = @us' expects the parameter '@userID', which was not supplied.

Will need your help! Thanks!

Comment: was there more information you were going to add to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you check the value of `UserID`, you will find that it is `Null`.

If you were attempting to find Users with a `NULL` `UserId` then you would execute:

```
string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM Account WHERE userID IS NULL";
                                                      ^^^^^^^
```

[Unrelated, but I would also suggest using `using` statements to wrap your connection and command.]

Comment: So you have your answer! A parameter needs to have a value when checking for equality.

Comment: Now the error becomes ' The parameterized query '(@userID nvarchar(4000))SELECT * FROM Account WHERE userID IS NU' expects the parameter '@userID', which was not supplied. '

Answer (score 0):

Like Mitch Wheat says, you need to check that the parameter has a value before checking for equality.  You can add a check to your function to ensure that it has a value:

```
public Account getAccount(string userID) { Account accountFound = null;
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userID))
          return accountFound;

//leave everything else
```

You'll then have to deal with the null value that's returned with whatever you have happening after the call to this function.